# How can I record and send IR signals with my USB IR transceiver?

Tags: infrared, ir

I have a MCE Vista/7 USB IR transceiver. I typically use it for controlling XBMC via a Media Center remote. I'm looking to repurpose it for something less than typical and I'm having a difficult time determining the best way to do it.

I have a [light](http://us.thegoallight.com/store/#!/~/product/category=1620116&id=15439010) that is controlled by an IR remote. Click the remote, the light goes on for a few moments. I want to capture that IR signal using my IR transceiver and save it. Then I'd like to be able to blast it back out of the transceiver, controlled by the computer.

I've messed with [EventGhost](http://www.eventghost.org/), but I don't know if I'm on the right track. I'm not doing home automation and don't need a bloated method to accomplish this simple task.

Is there a piece of software or method that I can easily capture, record, and reuse the IR signal coming from this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCE remotes use Philips RC6 IR remote control protocol. No software on the PC side is going to make the MCE IR receiver to accept anything but RC6 packets. So you will not be able to control your light with MCE IR blaster unless your light's remote is also using RC6.